# Python backslash will not go away

Tags: python, filepath, backslash

I am new to python trying to open a file in python using:

```
phys = "C:\\parsework\\glckpysdata.txt"
print phys
d = open(phys)
```

When I run I get:

```
C:\parsework\glckpysdata.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py\boxtest2.py", line 28, in <module>
    d = open(phys)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\parsework\\glckpysdata.txt'
```

I feel like I've tried everything (phys = r"C:\parsework\glckpysdata.txt", direct entry into the open command with double and single quotes/backslashes ect...) nothing seems to prevent it from reading the path with the double backslashes.
The most frustrating thing about this I have the exact same syntax in the same script and it works perfectly there:

```
thisguy = "C:\\parsework\\glckout\\"
thisguy += nam
g = open(thisguy)
```

is in the same script and works fine. Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: The "reading the path with the double backslashes" is irrelevant.  That's just the way Python shows \ in a string.  The file does not exist.  It has nothing to do with the \.  Check your directory listing.  Use `dir` and include the output in the question.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is not the double backslash in the path -- this is just an artifact from displaying the representation of the string in the error message.  The actual string does not contain double backslashes.

Your problem simply is that `C:\parsework\glckpysdata.txt` does not exist, just as the error message says.

By the way, to avoid this kind of issue, simply use forward slashes in paths:

```
phys = "C:/parsework/glckpysdata.txt"
```

Comment: Alright, filename was one letter off, I feel like an idiot, thanks.

Comment: @user1202297: "I feel like an idiot".  Now you know what to look for.  Don't forget to accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Either of the following is correct:

```
phys = "C:\\parsework\\glckpysdata.txt"
```

or

```
phys = r"C:\parsework\glckpysdata.txt"
```

The exception means that the file doesn't exist, or you don't have permissions to access it. Double-check the path and the filename (at a guess, are you missing an `h` in `glckpysdata.txt`?)

The double backslashes in the exception message are simply how embedded backslashes are displayed; every `\\` corresponds to a **single** backslash in the string.